# How Can I Change All Value of node Json and return same object dynamic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

> I want to encrypt only value and return same json with this code.

This code can get all value and all node of JSON but I don't know how can I change just only value and still same struct of Same object form Parse Json. Same Structuer of Json for dynamic not only example json but all of jsonstr

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonstr =
                "{\"timestamp\":\"2016-04-08 11:21:25\",\"apiKey\":\"jdtest\",\"data\":{\"adultQuantity\":3,\"childQuantity\":0,\"babyQuantity\":0,\"segmentList\":[{\"departCityCode\":\"PNZ\",\"arriveCityCode\":\"SHA\",\"departDate\":\"2016-04-19\"}]},\"H\":\"value\",\"c\":null,\"v\":\"\",\"w\":\"null\"}";
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            JObject _jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonstr);

            string str = Fun(_jObject);
        }

        public static string Fun(JObject obj)
        {
            string result = null;

            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                if (typeof(JObject) == item.Value.GetType())
                {
                    JObject child = (JObject)item.Value;
                    string tmp = Fun(child);
                    result += tmp;
                }
                else if (typeof(JArray) == item.Value.GetType())
                {
                    JArray _jarray = (JArray)item.Value;
                    foreach (var jitem in _jarray)
                    {
                        JObject jchild = (JObject)jitem;
                        string tmp = Fun(jchild);
                        result += tmp;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!(item.Value != null && item.Value.ToString().Trim().Equals("")))
                    {
                        result += string.Format("{0}={1},", item.Key, item.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static T JsonDeSerializerObj<T>(string json)
        {
            T t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            return t;
        }
    }
}
```

Code From : https://gist.github.com/seayxu/bf4f81988489a4d65144b92e1d0224cf

Old Json

```html
{
  "timestamp": "2016-04-08 11:21:25",
  "apiKey": "jdtest",
  "data": {
    "adultQuantity": 3,
    "childQuantity": 0,
    "babyQuantity": 0,
    "segmentList": [
      {
        "departCityCode": "PNZ",
        "arriveCityCode": "SHA",
        "departDate": "2016-04-19"
      }
    ]
  },
  "H": "value",
  "c": null,
  "v": "",
  "w": "null"
}
```

Expected To
(encrypt only value with my function)

```html
{
  "timestamp": "xtDeqvsMrA2l6lmsfUjs67wpn5vtwmyTZzFXc1si0xsbAIQqJJMqbTIr/vIDpPnRnbq5FnOP+Z2A7awIDsMcUXpHzQlPCkthYAnk3fMragnIMgsUVRUXSl8wMiszs54+d0p/EI1Z01qaEXYzW+gyOk+G674Ghhbf1Vo/Q/HpcjJh0I+Dy6L8bquaGQv//HosYX8FdP6arDgDDcmIsqnbnUQCThsp49jp6oONF4y/pmaXrXAwXi5omieeIkQgqaa2Aq0LuaUmeTnW0aLzTsl+IFn94f16/q2J8n8boweuvwroFqsusyBtwgvzxtVGNckE7Dd4V7gmfU36lhd8WOsvtg==",
  "apiKey": "xtDeqvsMrA2l6lmsfUjs67wpn5vtwmyTZzFXc1si0xsbAIQqJJMqbTIr/vIDpPnRnbq5FnOP+Z2A7awIDsMcUXpHzQlPCkthYAnk3fMragnIMgsUVRUXSl8wMiszs54+d0p/EI1Z01qaEXYzW+gyOk+G674Ghhbf1Vo/Q/HpcjJh0I+Dy6L8bquaGQv//HosYX8FdP6arDgDDcmIsqnbnUQCThsp49jp6oONF4y/pmaXrXAwXi5omieeIkQgqaa2Aq0LuaUmeTnW0aLzTsl+IFn94f16/q2J8n8boweuvwroFqsusyBtwgvzxtVGNckE7Dd4V7gmfU36lhd8WOsvtg==",
  "data": {
    "adultQuantity": "ytLjAaXk5Wedl8bbMfcfh4R5g1Mp1j3fNT2YMOsdlAXv1zi6lP0qIGrVImbs8eK9lwr11D/AwaSQSs2PlJlSHcXbp2zXTOQMvjUGhjY1KBTnf3NUjNkGcy5CaJp6gYVdrnf8p+++pPxhFNZm8UTCk3tcdI7+T8vYW/7YWII/qMB4MT2CF4A0pqDB7BcLSDGErE4MDPEB+PS/NNLKtuiFZjCsvb9Nj+R0DKWV0HsRIDbV5GpAqdqu0Xk4BQ7/qho8RsTTRvope7swC+Gngd3arlTGFXNax7cb0SNh+ttV9GWf2lGMne5uOtNHDEuknmTrlP61WoMmtULAjDU1TOMc3g==",
    "childQuantity": "ytLjAaXk5Wedl8bbMfcfh4R5g1Mp1j3fNT2YMOsdlAXv1zi6lP0qIGrVImbs8eK9lwr11D/AwaSQSs2PlJlSHcXbp2zXTOQMvjUGhjY1KBTnf3NUjNkGcy5CaJp6gYVdrnf8p+++pPxhFNZm8UTCk3tcdI7+T8vYW/7YWII/qMB4MT2CF4A0pqDB7BcLSDGErE4MDPEB+PS/NNLKtuiFZjCsvb9Nj+R0DKWV0HsRIDbV5GpAqdqu0Xk4BQ7/qho8RsTTRvope7swC+Gngd3arlTGFXNax7cb0SNh+ttV9GWf2lGMne5uOtNHDEuknmTrlP61WoMmtULAjDU1TOMc3g==",
    "babyQuantity": "ytLjAaXk5Wedl8bbMfcfh4R5g1Mp1j3fNT2YMOsdlAXv1zi6lP0qIGrVImbs8eK9lwr11D/AwaSQSs2PlJlSHcXbp2zXTOQMvjUGhjY1KBTnf3NUjNkGcy5CaJp6gYVdrnf8p+++pPxhFNZm8UTCk3tcdI7+T8vYW/7YWII/qMB4MT2CF4A0pqDB7BcLSDGErE4MDPEB+PS/NNLKtuiFZjCsvb9Nj+R0DKWV0HsRIDbV5GpAqdqu0Xk4BQ7/qho8RsTTRvope7swC+Gngd3arlTGFXNax7cb0SNh+ttV9GWf2lGMne5uOtNHDEuknmTrlP61WoMmtULAjDU1TOMc3g==",
    "segmentList": [
      {
        "departCityCode": "ytLjAaXk5Wedl8bbMfcfh4R5g1Mp1j3fNT2YMOsdlAXv1zi6lP0qIGrVImbs8eK9lwr11D/AwaSQSs2PlJlSHcXbp2zXTOQMvjUGhjY1KBTnf3NUjNkGcy5CaJp6gYVdrnf8p+++pPxhFNZm8UTCk3tcdI7+T8vYW/7YWII/qMB4MT2CF4A0pqDB7BcLSDGErE4MDPEB+PS/NNLKtuiFZjCsvb9Nj+R0DKWV0HsRIDbV5GpAqdqu0Xk4BQ7/qho8RsTTRvope7swC+Gngd3arlTGFXNax7cb0SNh+ttV9GWf2lGMne5uOtNHDEuknmTrlP61WoMmtULAjDU1TOMc3g==",
        "arriveCityCode": "ytLjAaXk5Wedl8bbMfcfh4R5g1Mp1j3fNT2YMOsdlAXv1zi6lP0qIGrVImbs8eK9lwr11D/AwaSQSs2PlJlSHcXbp2zXTOQMvjUGhjY1KBTnf3NUjNkGcy5CaJp6gYVdrnf8p+++pPxhFNZm8UTCk3tcdI7+T8vYW/7YWII/qMB4MT2CF4A0pqDB7BcLSDGErE4MDPEB+PS/NNLKtuiFZjCsvb9Nj+R0DKWV0HsRIDbV5GpAqdqu0Xk4BQ7/qho8RsTTRvope7swC+Gngd3arlTGFXNax7cb0SNh+ttV9GWf2lGMne5uOtNHDEuknmTrlP61WoMmtULAjDU1TOMc3g==SHA",
        "departDate": "ytLjAaXk5Wedl8bbMfcfh4R5g1Mp1j3fNT2YMOsdlAXv1zi6lP0qIGrVImbs8eK9lwr11D/AwaSQSs2PlJlSHcXbp2zXTOQMvjUGhjY1KBTnf3NUjNkGcy5CaJp6gYVdrnf8p+++pPxhFNZm8UTCk3tcdI7+T8vYW/7YWII/qMB4MT2CF4A0pqDB7BcLSDGErE4MDPEB+PS/NNLKtuiFZjCsvb9Nj+R0DKWV0HsRIDbV5GpAqdqu0Xk4BQ7/qho8RsTTRvope7swC+Gngd3arlTGFXNax7cb0SNh+ttV9GWf2lGMne5uOtNHDEuknmTrlP61WoMmtULAjDU1TOMc3g=="
      }
    ]
  },
  "H": "ytLjAaXk5Wedl8bbMfcfh4R5g1Mp1j3fNT2YMOsdlAXv1zi6lP0qIGrVImbs8eK9lwr11D/AwaSQSs2PlJlSHcXbp2zXTOQMvjUGhjY1KBTnf3NUjNkGcy5CaJp6gYVdrnf8p+++pPxhFNZm8UTCk3tcdI7+T8vYW/7YWII/qMB4MT2CF4A0pqDB7BcLSDGErE4MDPEB+PS/NNLKtuiFZjCsvb9Nj+R0DKWV0HsRIDbV5GpAqdqu0Xk4BQ7/qho8RsTTRvope7swC+Gngd3arlTGFXNax7cb0SNh+ttV9GWf2lGMne5uOtNHDEuknmTrlP61WoMmtULAjDU1TOMc3g==",
  "c": null,
  "v": "",
  "w": "null"
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you please post the implementation of the `Fun` method?

Comment: why not exncrypt the entire json? i mean all the values are encrypted... would it not be easier to just encrypt the whle json and skip all these logic?

Comment: Just only values

Comment: string jsonstr =
                "{\"timestamp\""2016-04-08 11:21:25\",\"apiKey\""jdtest\",\"data\":{\"adultQuantity\":3,\"childQuantity\":0,\"babyQuantity\":0,\"segmentList\":[{\"departCityCode\""PNZ\",\"arriveCityCode\""SHA\",\"departDate\""2016-04-19\"}]},\"H\""value\",\"c\":null,\"v\""\",\"w\""null\"}";
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            JObject _jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

            string str = Fun(_jObject);
            //Console.WriteLine(str+"\t");
            Console.WriteLine("{" + str + "}");

Comment: It's hard to just make the values be encrypted, turn the json into a model?

Comment: I don't know what todo.
How Can I use foreach and SetValue() ?

Comment: @EmphasizeSingle Did you got any progress sir? Could you pls accept it as the answer if you feel my post below is helpful to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have another idea which is using `JsonTextReader` to read the json string and write a new json string at the same time. And certainly it will encrypt the values. If your json content is regular, I think the code below can meet your requirement.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebMvcApp.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace WebMvcApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public string getstring()
        {
            string jsonstr = "{\"timestamp\":\"2016-04-08 11:21:25\",\"apiKey\":\"jdtest\",\"data\":{\"adultQuantity\":3,\"childQuantity\":0,\"babyQuantity\":0,\"segmentList\":[{\"departCityCode\":\"PNZ\",\"arriveCityCode\":\"SHA\",\"departDate\":\"2016-04-19\"}]},\"H\":\"value\",\"c\":null,\"v\":\"\",\"w\":\"null\"}";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonstr));
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject) {
                    writer.WriteStartObject();
                }
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject) {
                    writer.WriteEndObject();
                }
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray) {
                    writer.WriteStartArray();
                }
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
                {
                    writer.WriteEndArray();
                }
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
                {
                    writer.WriteComment(reader.Value.ToString());
                }
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(reader.Value.ToString());
                }
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                {
                    writer.WriteValue(reader.Value);
                }
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Integer)
                {
                    writer.WriteValue(reader.Value.ToString()+"encrypted");
                }if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
                {
                    writer.WriteValue(reader.Value.ToString()+"encrypted");
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the test result:

[image]

======================  See Above   =========================

I mean this, turn json string to model and encrypt each property one by one :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebMvcApp.Models;

namespace WebMvcApp.Controllers
{
    public class Root
    {
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
        public string apiKey { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
        public string H { get; set; }
        public string c { get; set; }
        public string v { get; set; }
        public string w { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int adultQuantity { get; set; }
        public int childQuantity { get; set; }
        public int babyQuantity { get; set; }
        public List<Dictionary<string,string>> segmentList { get; set; }
    }

        public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public Root getstring()
        {
            string jsonstr = "{\"timestamp\":\"2016-04-08 11:21:25\",\"apiKey\":\"jdtest\",\"data\":{\"adultQuantity\":3,\"childQuantity\":0,\"babyQuantity\":0,\"segmentList\":[{\"departCityCode\":\"PNZ\",\"arriveCityCode\":\"SHA\",\"departDate\":\"2016-04-19\"}]},\"H\":\"value\",\"c\":null,\"v\":\"\",\"w\":\"null\"}";
            Root root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(jsonstr);
            return encryptJson(root);
        }

        public Root encryptJson(Root root) {
            root.timestamp = root.timestamp == "null" ? "null" : encryptMethod(root.timestamp);
            root.apiKey = root.apiKey == "null" ? "null" : encryptMethod(root.apiKey);
            root.H = root.H == "null" ? "null" : encryptMethod(root.H);
            return root;
        }

        public string encryptMethod(string parameter)
        {
            return parameter + "encrypt";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it should be dynamic with text json Can change. But still encrypt

Comment: You mean that the Json content should be dynamic so you need to write code which can loop in the content and encrypt all the property?

Comment: Yes That I want it. Look good to me. Thank you So much.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir and it's really important to get your mark : ) many thanks